# Getting unexpected argument types with and implementing generic java interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I created a generic interface named Predicate and created a number of classes that implement this interface.

The following is my predicate interface:

```
package predicates;

interface Predicate<T> {
    public boolean startsWith(T t);
    public boolean accepts(T t);
    public boolean greaterThan(T t);
    public boolean subsetOf(T t);
    public boolean negation(T t);
    public boolean acceptsAllOf(T t);
    public boolean acceptsSomeOf(T t);
    public boolean acceptsMostOf(T t);
    public boolean mostAcceptsMostOf(T t);
    public boolean and(T t);
    public boolean or(T t);
}
```

The following is my implementation of the predicate interface called SubsetOf (Note that it doesn't do anything right now):

```
package predicates;

import java.util.Collection;

public class SubsetOf<T> implements Predicate<T> {

    public SubsetOf(Collection<T> t) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startsWith(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accepts(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean greaterThan(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean subsetOf(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean negation(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsAllOf(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsSomeOf(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsMostOf(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mostAcceptsMostOf(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean and(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean or(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    
    

}
```

And these two functions is where I am creating an object and running a test on it:

```
public static void subsetOf() {
        SubsetOf<String> predicate = new SubsetOf<String>( Arrays.asList("mad", "men") );
        List<Collection<? extends String>> tests = 
                Arrays.asList( 
                        Arrays.asList("mad", "men"),
                        Arrays.asList("men", "mad"),
                        Arrays.asList("men", "women", "rams", "mad"),
                        Arrays.asList("mad", "cowboy"),
                        Arrays.asList() );
        List<Boolean> oracle = Arrays.asList( true, true, false, false, true );
        
        test( "SubsetOf<String>(mad, men)", predicate, tests, oracle );             
    }
```

```
public static <T> void test( String msg, Predicate<T> predicate, List<T> tests, List<Boolean> expected ) {
        List<Boolean> actual = results( predicate, tests );
        
        System.out.print( pad(msg) );
        if( !actual.equals(expected) ) {
            System.out.println( " FAILURE" );
            for(int i=0; i<actual.size(); i++ ) {
                System.out.println( "\t\t" + tests.get(i) + "=>" + actual.get(i) + ":" + expected.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println( " SUCCESS" );
        }
    }
```

This particular line is the problem area:

```
test( "SubsetOf<String>(mad, men)", predicate, tests, oracle );
```

The issue I am having is that the two above sections of code cannot be changed in any way. I feel like I coded everything in a way that the inputs should match the function arguments, however I am getting the following error:

The method test(String, Predicate, List, List) in the type Tester is not applicable for the arguments (String, SubsetOf, List<Collection<? extends String>>, List)

I feel as though I have everything correctly stated and instantiated where is should recognize the SubsetOf as a Predicate, and that List<Collection<? extends string>> should be interpreted as List. I have been trying different configurations for hours but have made no progress. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because you now want your 3rd argument in the function `test(String, Predicate<T>, List<T>, List)`  to accept a List of Collections of `T`, but not a List of `T` as declared. You need to indicate the correct argument type in the signature of the `test` method. Also the construct like `List<Collection<? extends String>>` makes no sense as String is a final class and cannot be extended; it should be just `List<Collection<String>>`

Comment: Also, there's no point of letting the `SubsetOf<T>` be an implementation of `Predicate<T>` and then implement all the methods like `greaterThan` or `startsWith` inside as they seem off. Instead you can just make a default method directly in your Predicate interface that accepts a collection of `T`, but even then the Predicate<T> definition looks as a mix of unrelated (to a given type `T` methods) as, for instance, `greaterThan` makes sense for comparable types and `subsetOf` to work with 2 collections

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```java
List<Collection<String>> tests = 
                Arrays.asList( 
                        Arrays.asList("mad", "men"),
                        Arrays.asList("men", "mad"),
                        Arrays.asList("men", "women", "rams", "mad"),
                        Arrays.asList("mad", "cowboy"),
                        Arrays.asList() );
```

```java
public static <T> void test(String msg, Predicate<T> predicate, List<Collection<T>> tests, List<Boolean> expected )
```